# sheet styling not working while export data direct from database in laravel excel using maatwebsite/excel version 3.1

Tags: excel, laravel, styling, laravel-excel

I tried many ways to style my header but nothing worked. I tried each way given in documentation also tried many ways from multiple sites but style now visible in excel sheet.
Using this package:"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",

This is my code.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;

class AccessStatusExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithStyles
{
    protected $contents;

    public function __construct($contents)
    {
        $this->contents = $contents;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->contents;
    }
    public function headings(): array
    {

        return array(
            'コンテンツURL',
            'タイトル',
            'ステータス',
            '公開日時',
            'テンプレート',
            'ファイル種類',               
        );
    }
    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        $sheet->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray([
            'font' => [
                'bold' => true,
            ],
        ]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because I tried to export in .csv format. As CSV file does not support any style. I you have to style your sheet you should export in .xlxs format.